# Jmeter - HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Header Manager conflict

Tags: cookies, jmeter

**Hello everyone.**

I am working with JMeter and I found one conflict between HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Header Manager. I am not sure how to process it.

**What should be done:**

I need to add extra data into the "Cookie Data:" section from the "Request Body".

I found this solution:

1. Add "HTTP Header Manager".
2. Add name: "Cookie" with needed value.
   [image]
3. As you can see from the screenshot - I am adding "Cookie" values in the "HTTP Header Manager".
   As a result, I get this:
   [image]
4. As you can see from the screenshot - I was able to add data into the "Cookie Data:" request from the "Request Body".

**What's the problem:**

1. I use "HTTP Cookie Manager" too.
2. When I execute a sample with data that came from the "HTTP Cookie Manager" and data came from the "HTTP Header Manager" - JMeter doesn't add data from the "HTTP Header Manager".
   [image]
3. As you can see from the screenshot - I add the "Cookie" header into the "HTTP Header Manager".
4. As a result, I am expecting to get this data into the "Cookie Data" area of the request. But... I see only the data came from the "HTTP Cookie Manager".
   [image]
5. As you can see from the screenshot - added data from the "HTTP Header Manager" is missing in this "Cookie Data" section from the request.

I researched in google and try a lot of things - but without result.

Answer (score 0):

Headers will be available through the `Request Header` tab in the `Request` area.

[image]

If you want to add custom cookies, you can add them through a [Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

[image]

You can view the cookies through the Request tab in the [View Result Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

[image]

Comment: I tried many time with adding "User-Defined Cookies" from "HTTP Cookie Manger", but for some reason the values are not added to the "Cookie Data" request.

Comment: I can see only `name` and `value` pairs in your screenshot. You need to add `Domain`. **The "domain" is the hostname of the server (without http://); the port is currently ignored.**

Comment: Hey hey... it looks that works as expected. Many thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use both, you have 2 options:

1. Completely remove HTTP Cookie Manager and perform manual correlation of cookies by extracting the [`Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) value, perform the necessary amendments, construct the needed cookie and use HTTP Header Manager to set the desired [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header value
2. Use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and modify the cookie value using Groovy code on the fly. Something like:

   ```
   def manager = sampler.getCookieManager()

   0.upto(manager.getCookieCount(), { index ->
       def cookie = manager.get(index)
       if (cookie.getName() == 'cookie_you_are_looking_for') {
           cookie.setValue(cookie.getValue() + 'foo')
       }
   })

   sampler.setCookieManager(manager)
   ```

   More information: [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy)